# Log user in using django

Tags: python, django

I would like to scrape web app with authentication. I am planning on using django/python to build the app. The app should log a user in the backend, and pick list of tables and store those in Django.

BeautifulSoup will be most likely used to get list of tables.

What would be best approach to log a user with username and password, and crawl different pages of the backend.

Comment: Is the authentication of which you speak authentication needed on the site you are scraping, or just for people to log into the django site? Not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Scrapy](http://Scrapy.org) with this django-related feature :
http://doc.scrapy.org/experimental/djangoitems.html